# Reset via ssh on irresponsive machine

Tags: ssh, magic-sysrq

I have a machine I cannot physically access at the moment. Now this machine is irresponsive, in the sense that when I try to log in via ssh the output is

```
/bin/bash: Input/output error
```

and then the connection closes.
I want to remotely reset the machine via `echo 'reisub' > /proc/sysrq-trigger` (which I believe should be possible since the kernel and ssh are still running). I have tried the following

```
ssh -T <host> "echo 'reisub' > /proc/sysrq-trigger"
```

but ssh is still trying to call `/bin/bash` and gives the same error. Is there any way to run the command directly (via ssh) instead of first calling bash?

Answer (score 3):

Virtually all unix hosts use the The [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) SSH server to receive ssh connections. When you connect to OpenSSH sshd and request it to run a command, it will always use your login shell to run the command. If you run:

```
ssh -T <host> "echo 'reisub' > /proc/sysrq-trigger"
```

then the ssh server will execute the equivalent of this:

```
$SHELL -c "echo 'reisub' > /proc/sysrq-trigger"
```

where `$SHELL` is your login shell--/bin/bash or whatever.

One exception to this is that the SSH server *might* be configured to handle SFTP sessions without invoking an external program. *If* your host is configured this way, then this *might* work:

1. On your local system, create a file containing the text "reisub".
2. Make an SFTP connection to the remote system.
3. Navigate to the `/proc` directory and put your file into `sysrq-trigger`.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like disk probably died. if you can’t ssh you unlikely to be able to sftp. 
this is why there is IPMI, do you have access to board management or chassis management controller via IPMI or SNMP?